# Links don't work in internet explorer 10

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I found that hyper links in a webpage i develop don't work in internet explorer v10 or v9, i've been for a while looking for answer and i can't to figure out anything. If i change to compatible mode to 9 it doesn't work either, but in compatibility mode with internet explorer 8 links work properly. Coding is UTF8 and HTML5.

The site: http://www.barcimaster.com

Comment: From where I see it, the problem is not the links, but presumably the javascript behind it as they're not real links. But please don't put live links because your question will become obsolete as soon as it will be fixed. try to arrow down the problem and write a jsfiddle with the code causing trouble, it will be easier for us to help you once you've done that, and maybe you'll find the solution yourself in the process !

Comment: ok, but they are real links in many cases, like social buttons above no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine in my IE11, but from your answer to my remark, I had an illumination. The problem is not the links, but most probably the CSS+HTML slicing of your page. Here's how I see it : for some reasons, you've got an element overlapping your links in IE. Therefore, when you hover the links, you actually hover this overlapping elements, and you can't click on the links and actually don't even get the pointer (the hand with finger) when hovering it.

So what you need to do is review you HTML and CSS (from what I saw, you've got quite a lot of work on this) so that nothing overlaps your links in IE.

I'm not 100% sure of this, but that's a situation I ran through several times during my career, and this explanation was almost always the good one. The good thing is that with developer tools nowadays, it's quite easy to find overlapping elements !

Comment: sounds logic.. very, i'll take a look then.

Comment: so yes, it was it. Now i have to find wich layer is in top... any advise to find it quickly?

Comment: Right click > Inspect element , and see what comes back. Unfortunately I only have IE11 here so I can't help you further :-/

Comment: you already did it, thank you very very much, cup of tea for you if i could